# Install new version iw

Tags: pkg-config, iwlwifi

Trying to install a new version of iw. After extracting, i run the "make" command.

`/bin/sh/: 1: pkg-config: not found`

```
Can not found any development files for libnl
```

I have installed libnl-3-200 libnl-3-dev over the apt-get install command.
There is not any `libnl.pc` file `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` directory. I dont know how to fix this problem. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev
make clean
make
```

iw-3.11 then 'makes' without error or warning for me in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: i have installed libnl-genl-3-dev... still the same problem

Comment: Are you trying to compile the same version of wl? Which kernel version? uname -r

Comment: 3.2.0 is the version. Can you do me a favoir ? Copy and upload the files of libnl inside /usr/lib/pkgconfig. The ".pc" files. I would be very thankful.

Comment: I have: dbus-python.pc  libquvi-scripts.pc  notify-python.pc  pygoocanvas.pc  xvmc.pc
ibus-table.pc   nautilus-sendto.pc  pm-utils.pc       xorg-wacom.pc but nothing at all related to libnl. Which wl version are you compiling? I suggest you try iw-3.2.